# Loop de una funcion para varios archivos .csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bucles

Soy nuevo usando python.

Tengo un script que al ejecutarlo me recoge datos de un experimento, guardandolos en formato .csv. Los ficheros se guardan en una carpeta con la fecha de adquisicion (DATE) y dentro de esta en carpetas Run cada vez que realizo el experimento, recolectando ademas 5 sweeps para cada uno, de tal forma que la distribucion de ficheros es mäas o menos esta:

```
DATE/ Run_1 / File_sweep_1.csv,File_sweep_2.csv,File_sweep_3.csv,File_sweep_4.csv,File_sweep_5.csv
      Run_2 / File_sweep_1.csv,File_sweep_2.csv,File_sweep_3.csv,File_sweep_4.csv,File_sweep_5.csv
        .
        .
      Run_j / File_sweep_1.csv,File_sweep_2.csv,File_sweep_3.csv,File_sweep_4.csv,File_sweep_5.csv
```

Ahora utilizo otro script para analizar los datos de los experimentos, lo puedo hacer manualmente cambiando al ruta cada vez que quiera, pero considerando que la cantidad de ficheros .csv es mayor de 100 seria un trabajo tedioso y probablemente algun archivo se quede sin analizar. Mi idea es crear una especie de loop en el cual los datos sean siempre las mismas columnas para todos los ficheros.

Hasta el momento tengo algo asi:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


''' Insert here the Date to Analyze files '''

DATE = '2020-02-18'

os.chdir('MainPath' + DATE)

MainFolder = 'Main Path' + DATE
print('You are working on this directory:\n', os.getcwd(), '\n')
print('The subfolders in the directory are:\n',os.listdir(), '\n')


def LoadData():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(MainFolder):
        for dirs in dirs:
            print(os.path.sep + dirs)
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                print(os.path.sep + file)
                yield pd.read_csv(root + os.path.sep + file)
```

El problema reside en hacer un loop para que la funcion se aplique a cada sweep. Es decir que tan solo cambiando la fecha en DATE lea todos los ficheros dentro de las subcarpetas Run y aplique la funcion a File_sweep_1.csv, File_sweep_2.csv... File_sweep_5.csv.

Para ello tendria que usar pandas tal que:

```
for data in LoadData():    
    data = pd.read_csv(File_sweep_(i))
```

Y asi sucesivamente.

Algun consejo para poder conseguir hacer esto?
Gracias